# Why are there multiple classes inside a single dex file?

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I have created a bundle and trying to analyze it. I got some classes as per the screenshot inside of dex file.

My question is, why are there multiple classes inside the dex file, and if multiple classes must not be there then how to remove them properly?

**edits*** multiDexEnabled is false

[image: detailed image of a bundle in the android studio]

Comment: "My question is why there are multiple classes inside the dex file" -- there is overhead in dealing with DEX files, particularly prior to Android 5.0. Please bear in mind that platform support for multiple DEX files was only added in Android 5.0 -- for much of Android's existence, you had just one DEX file in your APK. "And if it must not be there than how to remove it properly?" -- what is "it"?

Comment: that is OK, and not is a problem. It is due to method amount limit per 1 dex file, which is 65535.

Comment: May be I didn't understand well, what is your problem actually?

Answer (score 0):

Dex files are like jar files. They contain classes, not in java but smali(compiled).